# Change x-axis ticks in pandas plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot

Yes, it is! Yet another question about ticks on a pandas plot. Yet, after searching ways to do this, I havent found a single method that works. So, I'm going to take my chances here.

So, I have this very simple dataframe:

```
{'barcode': {3848: 'N4099162017113226',
  4016: 'N4099162193713227',
  3931: 'N4099162017113226',
  4951: 'N4099162193713227',
  8844: 'N4639084100313189',
  2750: 'N4089163355413224',
  8833: 'N4639084100313189',
  5476: 'N4109161785913227',
  5076: 'N4099162193713227',
  6538: 'N4109161888813220',
  2934: 'N4089163374213223',
  3715: 'N4099162017113226',
  2410: 'N4089163374213223',
  4822: 'N4099162193713227',
  7668: 'N4639084100313189',
  1631: 'N4089163201613226',
  5727: 'N4619082362913181',
  1472: 'N4089163080013225',
  1118: 'N4089163013313224',
  6616: 'N4639083965813182',
  1216: 'N4089163020113220',
  934: 'N4089163005513227',
  5403: 'N4109161759113220',
  2727: 'N4089163355413224',
  5547: 'N4109161785913227',
  3206: 'N4099162017113226',
  7829: 'N4639083968113188',
  6530: 'N4109161888813220',
  3777: 'N4099162017113226',
  4336: 'N4099162177013222',
  975: 'N4089163023413226',
  2275: 'N4089163374213223',
  1161: 'N4089163023413226',
  4667: 'N4099162155013228',
  4685: 'N4099162173713225',
  1711: 'N4089163080013225',
  1615: 'N4089163079313226',
  3252: 'N4099162001813226',
  8487: 'N4639084100313189',
  3301: 'N4089163406513222',
  2863: 'N4089163355413224',
  1070: 'N4089163013113222',
  4689: 'N4109161759113220',
  712: 'N4089102505013185',
  6536: 'N4109161888813220',
  855: 'N4089163005513227',
  7706: 'N4639083991213185',
  2183: 'N4089163201613226',
  1020: 'N4089163009613222',
  2311: 'N4089163219613225',
  4726: 'N4099162168713229',
  890: 'N4089163013313224',
  3556: 'N4089163446213223',
  4619: 'N4099162168713229',
  2024: 'N4089163219613225',
  2607: 'N4089163355413224',
  6646: 'N4639083968113188',
  8852: 'N4639084100313189',
  4014: 'N4099162018913225',
  7173: 'N4619082370213183',
  4180: 'N4099162026013225',
  6025: 'N4109161943113225',
  4026: 'N4099162019513222',
  1725: 'N4089163189513220',
  6887: 'N4619082358813185',
  4102: 'N4099162020313222',
  1792: 'N4089163164413222',
  2161: 'N4089163344513223',
  4698: 'N4099162174513224',
  1819: 'N4089163111313223',
  1017: 'N4089163009613222',
  836: 'N4089163005513227',
  1051: 'N4089163013113222',
  1014: 'N4089163020113220',
  1081: 'N4089163013313224',
  2788: 'N4089163406513222',
  5094: 'N4109161785913227',
  3405: 'N4089163446213223',
  5153: 'N4109161759113220',
  7379: 'N4639083990813180',
  4516: 'N4099162151113225',
  7102: 'N4639083993213187',
  4542: 'N4099162155013228',
  2979: 'N4089163374213223',
  7559: 'N4639084081613180',
  2555: 'N4089163377413228',
  3972: 'N4099162157913229',
  5880: 'N4109161961813222',
  3655: 'N4099161990413228',
  1371: 'N4089163079313226',
  1528: 'N4089163080013225',
  3749: 'N4099162001813226',
  5038: 'N4099162177013222',
  5300: 'N4109161895313223',
  5780: 'N4109161913513226',
  4791: 'N4099162173713225',
  2139: 'N4089163288313228',
  3575: 'N4099161995813227',
  1820: 'N4089163219613225',
  1312: 'N4089163080013225',
  5154: 'N4099162193713227',
  1697: 'N4089163096213224',
  3658: 'N4099162001513223',
  3837: 'N4099162001813226',
  4923: 'N4099162168713229',
  860: 'N4089162991213227',
  2495: 'N4089163377413228',
  816: 'N4089162990813222',
  4895: 'N4099162181313220',
  6811: 'N4619082358813185',
  4545: 'N4099162138213221',
  1301: 'N4089163079313226',
  4479: 'N4099162157913229',
  2713: 'N4089163391913229',
  6075: 'N4109161961813222',
  5281: 'N4109161785913227',
  6087: 'N4109161895313223',
  3580: 'N4099162152613221',
  3388: 'N4099161990413228',
  3247: 'N4099161990513229',
  4821: 'N4109161759113220',
  3126: 'N4099162023713229',
  1494: 'N4089163074113229',
  7037: 'N4619082359813186',
  1555: 'N4089163079613229',
  1536: 'N4089163111313223',
  3868: 'N4099162016613220',
  3626: 'N4099162020313222',
  718: 'N4089102505013185',
  7055: 'N4639083991213185',
  4168: 'N4099162172313220',
  3997: 'N4099162020813227',
  2990: 'N4099162018913225',
  3853: 'N4099162019313220',
  7699: 'N4639084105313184',
  2790: 'N4089163344513223',
  3437: 'N4099162019513222',
  8715: 'N4639084077713186',
  1947: 'N4089163189513220',
  8658: 'N4639084081613180',
  8369: 'N4639083992013184',
  9186: 'N4639084670613184',
  4012: 'N4099162151113225',
  4311: 'N4099162174513224',
  4134: 'N4099162021513225',
  4292: 'N4099162166413224',
  4742: 'N4099162167913220',
  8205: 'N4639083990813180',
  1862: 'N4089163164413222',
  3355: 'N4099162017113226',
  4444: 'N4099162177013222',
  2611: 'N4089163446213223',
  1119: 'N4089163013313224',
  2455: 'N4089163284913220',
  3747: 'N4099162026013225',
  4289: 'N4099162155213220',
  908: 'N4089163015013223',
  2459: 'N4089163316713224',
  7589: 'N4639083968113188',
  4142: 'N4099162155013228',
  6508: 'N4109161913513226',
  4917: 'N4099162188013224',
  6983: 'N4619082373713181',
  1244: 'N4089163023413226',
  5854: 'N4109161871413228',
  5024: 'N4109091661613184',
  928: 'N4089163005513227',
  8038: 'N4639084011113188',
  3727: 'N4099162025113225',
  1131: 'N4089163020113220',
  4679: 'N4099162155013228',
  4574: 'N4099162166213222',
  3828: 'N4099162016913223',
  3738: 'N4099162016613220',
  8745: 'N4639084081913183',
  6052: 'N4109161871413228',
  5801: 'N4109161840613226',
  3768: 'N4099162166413224',
  4397: 'N4099162163813225',
  7354: 'N4619082373713181',
  4927: 'N4099162173713225',
  4606: 'N4099162151213226',
  1912: 'N4089163137013228',
  5541: 'N4109161782413229',
  8083: 'N4639084081613180',
  4348: 'N4099162071213227',
  8790: 'N4639084085213180',
  3466: 'N4099162138213221',
  4310: 'N4099162157913229',
  4835: 'N4099162167913220',
  1000: 'N4089163015013223',
  8343: 'N4639083991213185',
  4212: 'N4099162151113225',
  3411: 'N4099162018913225',
  6661: 'N4619082358913186',
  2485: 'N4089163295213225',
  4009: 'N4099162019313220',
  8799: 'N4639084101813185'},
 'length': {3848: 18,
  4016: 17,
  3931: 17,
  4951: 16,
  8844: 16,
  2750: 15,
  8833: 15,
  5476: 15,
  5076: 15,
  6538: 15,
  2934: 15,
  3715: 15,
  2410: 14,
  4822: 14,
  7668: 14,
  1631: 14,
  5727: 14,
  1472: 14,
  1118: 14,
  6616: 14,
  1216: 14,
  934: 14,
  5403: 14,
  2727: 14,
  5547: 14,
  3206: 14,
  7829: 14,
  6530: 14,
  3777: 13,
  4336: 13,
  975: 13,
  2275: 13,
  1161: 12,
  4667: 13,
  4685: 13,
  1711: 13,
  1615: 13,
  3252: 13,
  8487: 13,
  3301: 13,
  2863: 13,
  1070: 13,
  4689: 13,
  712: 13,
  6536: 13,
  855: 13,
  7706: 13,
  2183: 13,
  1020: 13,
  2311: 13,
  4726: 13,
  890: 13,
  3556: 13,
  4619: 12,
  2024: 12,
  2607: 12,
  6646: 12,
  8852: 12,
  4014: 12,
  7173: 12,
  4180: 12,
  6025: 12,
  4026: 12,
  1725: 12,
  6887: 12,
  4102: 12,
  1792: 12,
  2161: 12,
  4698: 12,
  1819: 12,
  1017: 12,
  836: 12,
  1051: 12,
  1014: 12,
  1081: 12,
  2788: 12,
  5094: 12,
  3405: 12,
  5153: 12,
  7379: 12,
  4516: 12,
  7102: 12,
  4542: 12,
  2979: 12,
  7559: 12,
  2555: 12,
  3972: 12,
  5880: 12,
  3655: 12,
  1371: 12,
  1528: 12,
  3749: 12,
  5038: 12,
  5300: 12,
  5780: 12,
  4791: 12,
  2139: 11,
  3575: 11,
  1820: 11,
  1312: 11,
  5154: 11,
  1697: 11,
  3658: 11,
  3837: 11,
  4923: 11,
  860: 11,
  2495: 11,
  816: 11,
  4895: 11,
  6811: 11,
  4545: 11,
  1301: 11,
  4479: 11,
  2713: 11,
  6075: 11,
  5281: 11,
  6087: 11,
  3580: 11,
  3388: 11,
  3247: 11,
  4821: 11,
  3126: 11,
  1494: 11,
  7037: 11,
  1555: 11,
  1536: 11,
  3868: 11,
  3626: 11,
  718: 11,
  7055: 11,
  4168: 11,
  3997: 11,
  2990: 11,
  3853: 11,
  7699: 11,
  2790: 11,
  3437: 11,
  8715: 11,
  1947: 11,
  8658: 11,
  8369: 11,
  9186: 11,
  4012: 11,
  4311: 11,
  4134: 11,
  4292: 11,
  4742: 11,
  8205: 11,
  1862: 11,
  3355: 11,
  4444: 11,
  2611: 11,
  1119: 11,
  2455: 11,
  3747: 11,
  4289: 11,
  908: 11,
  2459: 11,
  7589: 11,
  4142: 11,
  6508: 11,
  4917: 11,
  6983: 11,
  1244: 11,
  5854: 11,
  5024: 11,
  928: 11,
  8038: 11,
  3727: 11,
  1131: 11,
  4679: 10,
  4574: 10,
  3828: 10,
  3738: 10,
  8745: 10,
  6052: 10,
  5801: 10,
  3768: 10,
  4397: 10,
  7354: 10,
  4927: 10,
  4606: 10,
  1912: 10,
  5541: 10,
  8083: 10,
  4348: 10,
  8790: 10,
  3466: 10,
  4310: 10,
  4835: 10,
  1000: 10,
  8343: 10,
  4212: 10,
  3411: 10,
  6661: 10,
  2485: 10,
  4009: 10,
  8799: 10}}
```

which looks like this:

```
 barcode  length
3848  N4099162017113226  18    
4016  N4099162193713227  17    
3931  N4099162017113226  17    
4951  N4099162193713227  16    
8844  N4639084100313189  16    
...                 ...  ..    
3411  N4099162018913225  10    
6661  N4619082358913186  10    
2485  N4089163295213225  10    
4009  N4099162019313220  10    
8799  N4639084101813185  10
```

This df actually has the following shape: `[4359 rows x 2 columns]` and the smallest value of length is 1.

Now, when I create a histogram of this df using the following code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30,10))
freq, bins, patches = plt.hist(df['length'],label='Number of ESL/Number of units', bins = 19,color=['#A0E8AF'])


bin_centers = np.diff(bins)*0.5 + bins[:-1]

n = 0
for fr, x, patch in zip(freq, bin_centers, patches):
    height = int(freq[n])
    plt.annotate("{}".format(height),
               xy = (x, height),             
               xytext = (0,0.1),             
               textcoords = "offset points",
               ha = 'center', va = 'bottom'
               )
    n = n+1

plt.legend()
plt.show
```

I get the following plot:

[image]

This is all very well, but the x-axis shows ticks spaced by 2.5 units. Weird, because I have only integer values. What I'm looking for are ticks every 1 unit.

I've tried using `bins` (e.g., `bins = len(ACKV_df_unvectored['length'].unique())`) but it doesn't help at all. I know it's only aesthetics, but it's annoying.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) You don't just have integer values, `bins=19` in histogram might make your bins non-integers. 2) Regardless of the bins, you can force your ticks to be integer with [`MultipleLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html).

Comment: In how far is this a pandas plot? Seems like ordinary matplotlib to me.